# stringWithFormat vs. initWithFormat on NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I am wondering what differences such as disadvantages and/or advantages there are to declaring an NSString this way:

```
NSString *noInit = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"lolcatz %d", i];
```

as opposed to:

```
NSString *withInit = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hai %d", i];
```

What was the motivation of putting `stringWithFormat` instead of just having the `initWithFormat` way of initializing the string?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`stringWithFormat:` returns an autoreleased string; `initWithFormat:` returns a string that must be released by the caller. The former is a so-called "convenience" method that is useful for short-lived strings, so the caller doesn't have to remember to call `release`.

Comment: Beaten to the punch by 32 seconds. :-)

Comment: Actually;  it is the `+alloc` that returns the retained instance... the `init*` doesn't change the retain count (but it may -- will, in this case -- return a different instance than was called).

Answer (score 5):

I actually came across [this blog](http://akosma.com/2009/01/28/10-iphone-memory-management-tips/) entry on memory optimizations just yesterday. In it, the author gives specific reasons why he chooses to use `[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"..."]` instead of `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"..."]`. Specifically, iOS devices may not auto-release the memory pool as soon as you would prefer if you create an autorelease object.

The former version requires that you manually `release` it, in a construct such as this:

```
NSString *remainingStr = nil;
if (remaining > 1)
    remainingStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"You have %d left to go!", remaining];
else if (remaining == 1)
    remainingStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"You have 1 left to go!"];
else
    remainingStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"You have them all!"];

NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Level complete! %@", remainingStr];

[remainingStr release];

[self displayMessage:msg];
```

Here, `remainingStr` was only needed temporarily, and so to avoid the autorelease (which may happen MUCH later in the program), I explicitly handle the memory as I need it.

Comment: It a choice between premature optimization and clear concise code. Premature optimizations can be resolved later by analyzing the performance, unclear code is (usually) forever.