# Append integers to Objective C variable names

Tags: ios, objective-c, variables

I am new to Objective C. What my code currently does is create a new **Card** object, assigns properties to the object and then adds the **Card** object to the **cards** array. The value **numberOfCards** varies.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCards; i++) {

    Card *addCard = [Card new];

    addCard.balance = [balanceArray objectAtIndex:i];
    addCard.date = [dateArray objectAtIndex:i];
    addCard.name = [nameArray objectAtIndex:i];
    addCard.number = [numberArray objectAtIndex:i];

    [cards addObject:addCard];
}
```

However, what I want to do is give each card a unique name. For example, if **numberOfCards** was n, then we would get the Card variable names of **addCard1**, **addCard2** ... **addCardn**.
So how can I append **i** onto addCard?

Cheers

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I want each card to have a unique name. Otherwise I'd have a lot of **addCard**.

Comment: can i know why you need to go with different variables for card names. you can pick the cards from the array that you are using. can you explain your requirement clearly

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
NSString *cardName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"addCard%i", i + 1];

addCard.name = cardName;
```

Comment: He meant the variable name `cardName` not its property `name` which is of type `NSString`

Comment: Well, his comment did say "I want each card to have a unique name. Otherwise I'd have a lot of addCard." and not "I want each card *variable* name to have a unique name..."

Answer (score 0):

In order to chain a number to a string all you have to do is:

```
 NSString *cardNewName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%i",cardName,cardNumber];
```

The idea is to build a format of string and then chain the necessary parameters.
%@ is for string
%i is for integer
%f for float 
etc.

It's better to use stringWithFormat then [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:...] - for an extended information please take a look at the following question:
[stringWithFormat vs. initWithFormat on NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898974/stringwithformat-vs-initwithformat-on-nsstring)

Comment: stringWithFormat vs. initWithFormat - That only really makes a difference in non-ARC projects, which have not been the norm since before iOS 5.  There is a small difference under ARC but it doesn't matter for most people.

Comment: Yes I know.
But I believe that when you call stringWithFormat the garbage collector released it immediately. Moreover, I think it's more elegant.
Cheers

Comment: Actually it's the other way around.  The alloc/init version will be released immediately after it is finished being used, while the convenience constructor will release it on the next main loop pass.  Furthermore let's try to avoid using the term "garbage collector" since that doesn't exist in Objective-C anymore, and never did in iOS.  I think you meant to say it will be released in the next autorelease pool drain.  Elegance, also, is just a matter of preference and should be stated as such ;).